# How to upload Dockerfile to dockerhub?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

Few docker images have a Dockerfile tab with its content. For example
https://hub.docker.com/r/marvambass/nginx-ssl-secure/
https://hub.docker.com/r/marvambass/nginx-ssl-secure/dockerfile

When I uploaded a docker image to dockerhub. No such tab was created. I also dont see any option to upload a Dockerfile in the dashboard. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the Dockerfile is only shown for repositories which have automated builds set up. See: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/ and https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/ on how to set it up. This is a walkthrough: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz96JV8S-Bk on how to set up one.